# Unable to reference domain correctly in multiple server

Tags: php, css

I deploy two server for production. One to hold php files and the other to hold static(css,js)files.

in config.php

```
$path ="https://mystaticdomain.com/";
```

Now to centralize the path access, I defined a variable to hold the path for the css and js files.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $path;?>css/style.css">
 <script src="<?php echo $path;?>js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

The config files are in the document root. The above header file that includes the config resides inside 'inc' folder after document root.I include the config file in the header like this:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config.php');
```

What happens is, instead of fetching the files from the path specified in the config, it reference to the main domain like this: www.mydomain.com.

If I hardcode the path in header itself without including the config file like this, it works!

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://mystaticdomain.com/css/style.css">
  <script src="https://mystaticdomain.com/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Can anyone see what's the underlying problem here please?

Comment: $path ="mystaticdomain.com/"; is not correct path. You should mention protocol http or https

Comment: @Samir, it is starting with https://

Comment: are you getting correct URL when you use $path?  Have you inspected or viewed source? It seems $path became change somewhere

Comment: @Samir, that's right ,i changes to the main domain where the config file reside.

Comment: Change the `include` to a `require` and check the error logs to see what they say

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a protocol, or the href/src attributes will be treated as relative urls.

So the `$path` variable should start with either `http://`, `https://` or if you may need to use a mix of both for some reason, `//` which means the browser will use the current protocol to access the other server.